# Deleting Duplicates From a Doubly Linked List in C

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list, buckets

I am trying to work with a doubly linked list of SAT grades between 200-800. I need to remove from all the duplicates from the list, i.e. make sure each grade appears only once by deleting all its duplicates.

```
#define HIGHEST_GRADE 800

typedef struct dListNode{
    int* dataPtr;
    struct dListNode* next;
    struct dListNode* prev;
}DListNode;

typedef struct dList

{
    DListNode* head;
    DListNode* tail;
}DList;

void removeDuplicates(DList* lst)
{
    int i;
    int gradesBucket [numOfGrades];
    DListNode* temp;
    temp = lst->head;

    for(i=200 ; i<HIGHEST_GRADE ; i++) /*creating 600 buckets - each bucket for a grade*/
        gradesBucket[i] = FALSE;

    while (temp)
    {
        if ((gradesBucket [*temp->dataPtr]) == TRUE) /*if current grade has already  */
                                                     /* appeared earlier on the list */
        {
            deleteFromList (temp);  /*delete that grade's cell*/
        }
        else
            gradesBucket[*temp->dataPtr] = TRUE; /* mark grade bucket as true, meaning */
                                                 /* the grade already appeared*/
        temp = temp->next; /*moving on to next grade*/
    }
}

void deleteFromList(DListNode*  toRemove)
{
    toRemove->prev->next = toRemove->next;
    toRemove->next->prev = toRemove->prev;

    deAllocateListCell (toRemove);    
}

void deAllocateListCell (DListNode* cell)
{
    free (cell->dataPtr);
    free (cell);
}
```

Please help me understand what's wrong.

---

here's the fixed code, which still doesn't work properly. Now it compiles but nothing is shown on screen. And by the way, I dont need to take care of deleting the head, because the first number can never be a duplicate... but I took care of it in case the head was NULL;
I also send the previous cell of the one i want to delete, to the function deleteFromList. It still doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
    void deleteFromList(DList* lst, DListNode*  p)
{

DListNode* del_cell = p->next;   /* cell to delete*/

if (p->next->next == NULL) /*if cell to remove is the tail*/
{
    deAllocateListCell (p->next); /* freeing current tail */
    lst->tail = p;  /* p is the new tail */
    p->next = NULL; /* tail points to NULL */
}
else /* if cell to remove is not the tail (note: can't be head beacuse no duplicates can be found in the first grade) */
{
    p->next = del_cell->next;
    del_cell->next->prev = p;
    deAllocateListCell (del_cell);
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly does not work ?

Answer (score 2):

The code of your function `deleteFromList()` doesn't account for (literal) edge cases: Deleting the first or last node of a list.

Plus, your code dereferences a pointer to a deallocated node; the pointer can become outright invalid, or the `free()` function can overwrite its contents (as the Microsoft Debug C RunTime is known to).

Comment: Just to expand on this. The first two lines in deleteFromList assume that ->prev and ->next are not null, you should check for this. Also after deleteFromList has been called, temp now points to an invalid deleted node. A better solution is to have deleteFromList return the next node for you, and then use either this value, or advance to the next node manually in your else condition

Comment: What @noggin182 said, but also, deleting the first element will not modify the `head` pointer.

Comment: Thank u first of all, I will try to take care the head and tail cases and will let u know

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to be specific - What is it that doesn't work? Does your code compile? Do you get an error during runtime? You don't get the results you expected in a scenario?
2. Your `deleteFromList` function should take care of removing the head or tail (That is when `toRemove->prev` or `toRemove->next` are null (respectively).
3. `temp = lst->head;` and what happens when `lst` is null? You'll get a run-time error
4. You are not updating `head` or `tail` in case they are deleted

That's what I found in first glance.

Comment: Thank u first of all. The code does not compile and gets stuck.. I will try to take care the head and tail cases and will let u know

Comment: @user2290597
OK, so can you provide the compilation error you get?
Also, if you made changes to the code, I would suggest editing the question with the updated code..

Answer (score 0):

you should write `while(temp->next)` for correcting this....and also u can simply deallocate the node using free. and to eliminate dangling pointer problem you should make it NULL after freeing that node

Comment: No! Changing it to while(temp->next) will just introduce a new problem and not fix anything. while(temp->next) will be exactly the same as it is currently, but miss the last node!

Comment: when temp->next will be NULL it will stop so it stops for the last node so that will be not the problem i think.  and i am not understanding this clearly ` temp = lst->head`

Comment: when temp->next is NULL, is means there is no node AFTER the current one, the current node (temp) still needs to be processed though. The while condition is evaluated before each iteration

Comment: we can use do while loop for this i think.

Comment: Not really, in that case, when would you update the value of temp? it would need to be inside the while loop. so you either going to miss the first one or the last one